# how to detect upside down face?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, dlib

I would like to detect upright and upside-down faces, however faces weren't recognized in upside-down images.

I used the dlib library in Python with `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`.

Is there a library that can recognize upright and upside-down faces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the same library to detect upside down faces. If the library is unable to detect the face initially, transform it 180° and check again. If it is recognized in this condition, you know it was an upside down face.

Comment: Yes. It's a good way! May will it have a good training that focus on upright and upside down faces?

Answer (score 1):

I am just looking for answer, and figured it out, the idea is to detect the eye and mouth coordinates, if the eyes' coordinates below the mouth, or failure of detection, then maybe a up-side-down face.

Check it out here how to grab the coordinates
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/10/detect-eyes-nose-lips-jaw-dlib-opencv-python/